# Sharing the same egress IP address across multiple different projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

We have our project hosted in GCP. Now we setup separate projects for some of our customers with exact same configuration with our current project but with different VPC (some customers want single-tenant instance for enhanced security).

Under this setup, we want our vendors to not know about our multiple VPCs (ie we don't want to keep asking them to update IP allowlists). Is there a way to share the same egress IP address across multiple separate GCP projects?

Comment: Not a programming question. You should be asking on [SF]

Comment: Yes, by using a proxy or tunnel to forward traffic. You can configure your own or use proxies like VPC connectors. OpenSSH has tunnels built in.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you should look into is Shared VPCs as you setup the [Cloud NAT in the host project](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#interaction-shared-vpc) so then all your service projects share it for egress traffic.

It might work better for your app/infra setup too, but AFAIK there isn’t a straightfwd migration path from regular project VPCs to service VPCs so you pretty much have to get your Shared VPC host project and service projects setup and then rebuild your VMs or GKE clusters on it. Not all services support Shared VPCs either so I suggest you do your research first.